# Message Web Socket get exception a method was called at an unexpected time

Tags: c#, windows-8, websocket, windows-store-apps, async-await

Hi Im using MessageWebSocket in my windows store app but when I call method  mws() I get:

> A method was called at an unexpected time

I need call this method from another class because I want use the same MessageWebSocket for one connection and that is reason why is my method static.

```
    private static MessageWebSocket messageWebSocket = null;
    public static MessageWebSocket mws()
    {
        if (messageWebSocket == null)
        messageWebSocket =  new MessageWebSocket();
        return  messageWebSocket;
    }

private async void websocketRequestRegisterDevice(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        cos.WriteRawBytes(new byte[] { 7, 1, 0, 0 });
        req.WriteTo(cos);
        mws();
        mws().Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Binary;
        mws().MessageReceived += websocketResponseRegisterDevice;
        await mws().ConnectAsync(server);
        messageWriter = new DataWriter(mws().OutputStream);
        messageWriter.WriteBytes(buff);
        await messageWriter.StoreAsync();
    }
```

I call it in async method but if I want use await write me for example message type is not awaitable.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably calling `ConnectAsync` on a connected socket.

So you'd want something like this:

```
private static Task<MessageWebSocket> messageWebSocket = null;
public static Task<MessageWebSocket> mws()
{
    if (messageWebSocket == null)
        messageWebSocket = CreateMessageWebSocket();
    return  messageWebSocket;
}

private static async Task<MessageWebSocket> CreateMessageWebSocket()
{
    var ret = new MesesageWebSocket();
    await ret.ConnectAsync();
    return ret;
}

private async Task websocketRequestRegisterDevice(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    cos.WriteRawBytes(new byte[] { 7, 1, 0, 0 });
    req.WriteTo(cos);
    var s = await mws();
    s.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Binary;
    s.MessageReceived += websocketResponseRegisterDevice;
    messageWriter = new DataWriter(s.OutputStream);
    messageWriter.WriteBytes(buff);
    await messageWriter.StoreAsync();
}
```

I also changed your `async void` method to `async Task`, since you should avoid `async void`. However, note a few things that are still not optimal:

1. There's better ways to handle connection sharing than static fields.
2. Your various methods are still installing multiple handlers for `MessageReceived`, so they will probably get confused.

Comment: thx for answer but  await ret.ConnectAsync() this method need parameters and Im not sure if I add null parameter it will ok, second problem is if I use your task method I cannot use mws().Control and  mws().MessageReceived they are not available.

Comment: @PavolFranek: Updated. If I may suggest, please find a mentor at your workplace or school that you can ask advice from.